# Update pivot tables with filters using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

So far I haven't used VBA with pivot tables. Now I would like to update (refresh) 2 pivot tables and set the filter for the calendar week to the last full week.

**My questions / problems here are:**

1) Do I actually need the `.ClearAllFilters` lines or can I set the filter also without it ?
2) Can I check before setting the filter if the corresponding item (e.g. the week number 13) exists in my table ? Otherwise I would try to filter for something that doesn't exist (yet).
3) Do I write the code for this the right way or is there a shorter / better way for this ? E.g. I wasn't sure if `With` within `With` would makes sense here.

**My code:**

```
Dim varLastSunday As Date, varWeekNumber As Integer

varLastSunday = Date - Weekday(Date, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
varWeekNumber = CLng(Format(varLastSunday, "ww"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets(4)
    .Range("StartColumns").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    .PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("WEEK_NUMBER").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("WEEK_NUMBER").CurrentPage = varWeekNumber
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("week").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("week").CurrentPage = varWeekNumber
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: 1. do a test 2. probably yes, with DLookup() as one option 3. `With` can be nested but not seeing why you would in this code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because you are dealing with a PageField (i.e. a field that is in the Filters pane and that has "Select Multiple Items" unchecked) then no, I don't believe you need to clear filters. But my advice...just leave it in there...it won't hurt.
2. Easier simply to put some kind of error handling in your code to pick up any errors if the item doesn't exist. If you simply want to ignore any error, put an On Error Resume Next statement at the top of your block of code. Alternately you may want to advise the user that the PivotTable has not been filtered. If you clarify what you want to do, I'll post a code snippet.
3. Note that if both these pivottables share the same datasource, you don't need to refresh both caches, because they share a cache. If that's the case, then just get rid of the 2nd Refresh line.
4. Can you clarify why you are hiding the column? Does it get unhidden later? Is it likely to be unhidden whenever you run this code?
5. If this is all your code is doing, then I probably wouldn't bother turning off screenupdating. But again, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeffrey - this is great ! :) (This is only a small part of my code but the rest I have done before so just wanted to check on this. )

Comment: You answered almost all my questions and item 3 is a great thing to know (they do share the same source). The only thing I am not sure about is the error handling. In my case this will be filtered every Monday by the previous calendar week so the only case I would like to cover here is to show a message box in case there is no data available with this specific week number. I am thinking of something like On Error GoTo ErrMsg but I don't know how to cover this specific error.